# How to get the "correct" user-facing path for an application stored in /System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications?

Tags: macos

I'm writing a macOS application that allows the user to select an application they would like to be launched. I then need to save the path to this application in a manner that will work across different macOS versions and systems.

The code for selecting the application is simple enough:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:@[@"app"]];

[openPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result != NSModalResponseOK) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Selected file: %@", [[openPanel URL] path]);
}];
```

If the user selects Safari.app in an updated installation of macOS 13 or 14, they get the following path:

```
/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications/Safari.app
```

This path, while *technically* correct, does not work for my purposes. As far as the user is concerned, Safari.app is located in `/Applications`, and the fact that `/Applications` is now technically a firmlink combining together several different folders will only confuse them. Further, such a path will not work on earlier versions of macOS, or systems that do not have an update for Safari that comes from a "Rapid Security Response".

I need some way of taking this path and resolving it to a more user-friendly and backwards compatible path. At least in the case of Safari, it needs to be `/Applications/Safari.app`, but it needs to work for any other application that may end up buried within `/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes`.

Is there a better method than hardcoding in a check for `/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications` and assuming that the version of the file the user normally sees is in `/Applications`? I'm not inclined to do that, because I don't know what other files might end up buried within ``/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes`, or if Apple might end up creating yet another strange folder like this that confuses where files are actually located.